# How to map a parent to a child with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following classes

```
class Condition{
    public Long id;
    public Long ParentConditionId;
    public Int order;
}

class NotCondition extends Condition {
    public Condition childCondition;
}

class BooleanCondition extends Condition {
    public Collection<Condition> children;
}

class StringCondition extends Condition {
    public String value;
}
```

These classes are represented by a condition table with the following columns

```
Id bigint
Type varchar
ConditionOrder int
StringValue varchar
ParentConditionId bigint
```

How do I map the NotCondition to its child using hibernate mapping so that the childs ParentConditionId column contains the id of the NotCondition?

My mapping file is

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="conditions.Condition" table="Condition">
        <id column="Id" name="id" access="field">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>

        <discriminator type="string" column="Type"/>
        <property name="order" column="ConditionOrder" access="field"/>
        <property name="parentConditionId" column="ParentConditionId" access="field"/>
        <subclass name="conditions.NotCondition" discriminator-value="NOT">
            <!-- What to put here? -->
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="conditions.BooleanCondition" discriminator-value="BOOLEAN">
            <list name="children" access="field" cascade="all" lazy="false">
                <key><column name="ParentConditionId"></column></key>
                <list-index column="ConditionOrder"/>
                <one-to-many class="conditions.Condition"/>
            </list>
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="conditions.StringCondition" discriminator-value="STRING" >
            <property name="value" column="StringValue" access="field"/>
        </subclass>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi, why are you using a Long ParentConditionId and not a Condition parentCondition?

Comment: @MauricePerry Beacuse I want to be able to add another child to a Boolean condition without having to pass the full condition tree

Comment: I don't see how declaring it as a Long would prevent it

Comment: @MauricePerry It was so that I could save a Boolean (id=1) with two children, then at a later stage I could save a StringCondition and set its ParentConditionId to 1 and save it so it is linked to the Boolean without needing to have all the details of the Boolean when saving the extra child. I might be doing something stupid though since I only started looking at hibernate today, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well, if you do something like: child.parentCondition = (Condition)session.load(1), you get a proxy to the object, where only the id is set. I'm not sure however whether the parent object would be read before the child is saved or not. You can check that by enabling SQL logging. In any case, it would be a small price to pay for the convenience of using objects instead of IDs (after all, it's the purpose of an ORM isn't it?)

Answer (score 0):

explore these :

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

I suggest you to use annotations..

Below link contains both Annatation and xml configurations..

[link here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritence-table-per-hierarchy-mapping/)

Answer (score 0):

First, in class Condition, I would replace:

```
public Long ParentConditionId;
```

with:

```
public Condition parentCondition;
```

I would map is like so:

```
<many-to-one name="parentCondition" class="conditions.Condition" column="ParentConditionId" />
```

then, I would map childCondition (in subclass NotCondition) as:

```
<one-to-one name="childCondition" class="conditions.Condition" property-ref="parentCondition" />
```

Comment: I made these changes and when I saved a NotCondition with a StringCondition as the child only the NotCondition was saved. I changed the NotCondition to <many-to-one name="condition" foreign-key="Id" column="ParentConditionId" access="field" class="conditions.Condition"
                         cascade="all" unique="true"  /> and it was closer to what I need, the problem is that the NotConditions ParentId contains the childs id instead of the StringCondition containing the parents id. Is there a way to reverse this?

Comment: This is strange. Did you assign the NotCondition to the parentCondition of the StringCondition?